# Dynamic import not working in netlify (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, netlify, dynamic-import

I'm trying to deploy my reactjs application which uses @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import, the application works fine on my localhost, but when i deploy it on netlify, only the root url works (ex: mysite.netlify.com), all other url's with slug (ex: mysite.netlify.com/Visit) doesn't work, it simply returns 404 page not found even though i have defined routes and working on my localhost.

i have the following settings in my .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

and in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    ...
}
```

and i have the following imports on my App.js

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Photography = lazy(() => import('../Form1/Main.js'));
const Visit = lazy(() => import('../Form2/Main.js'));
```

is there anything missing or i need to make it work on netlify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with dynamic imports - this is an issue with your Netlify config. Add a `_redirects` file to the public root of your project. With the following content:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

More info [here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/)

An alternative is to add a `netlify.toml` file but this is more complex and will achieve the same result. More info [here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/)

Comment: I work in tech support @ Netlify and I also think this is the likely correct answer :)

Comment: @Jonathan Irwin i tried your solution, but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is the 404 page your own 404 or the netlify one?

Comment: @Jonathan Irwin it's a netlify one

Comment: @sam then I think perhaps you don't have it setup correctly - the above should redirect all requests to your index file.. What folder did you add the _redirects file to? If you are using create react app it needs to be the /public folder

Comment: @Jonathan Irwin i'm not using create react app, i tried both inside public/ and on the root folder but i din't work :(

Comment: This started happening to me as soon as I introduced dynamic imports using React.lazy, I reverted the changes & it works perfectly. Tried deploying on S3/Cloudfront it works great there, don't know what's going on here. Error on console is "Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=symbol&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."